# Performance issue after migrating from MongoDB 2.6 to MongoDB 3.2 + WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

We are migrating our MongoDB 2.6 database to MongoDB 3.2.10 + WiredTiger. After migrating, instead of improving performance, we've observed degraded read/write response time.

The only advantage is that the database size was reduced by nearly 40%.

We are now running 2.6 and 3.2.10 + WiredTiger on two different stand-alone servers.

All test reports are negative for WiredTiger.

I didn't find any good reason for migrating to 3.2.10 + WiredTiger now.

Are there any tuning parameters for 3.2.10 + WiredTiger?

Is WiredTiger mature enough for a Production environment?

I recently read [a blog post](https://blog.clevertap.com/sleepless-nights-with-mongodb-wiredtiger-and-our-return-to-mmapv1/) where they are facing problems with Mongo 3.0 and 3.2.9 WiredTiger.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the [Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epe3Y.png) for read comparison test and other detials

Answer (score 0):

Please find the  [Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFMVd.png) with comparing 2.6 , 3.2 WT snappy,3.2 WT zlib and 3.2 No Compression with read test and other details.

My observation is 3.2 WT is failing with non indexed property.

also please find my mongo config

```
mongod_WT_snippy.conf
```

storage:
    dbPath: 'C:\dataWT_snappy\'
    directoryPerDB: true
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    wiredTiger:
        collectionConfig: 
            blockCompressor: "snappy"

```
mongod_WT_snippy.conf
```

did i miss any parameter ?